# app icon is appear before splash screen when expo app open in android version 12 or 13

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, splash-screen, appicon

I am working on expo project. Problem is in some latest android vesion like, 12 or 30. app icon is apear before splash screen that's look very awkward. Please let me know how can we fix it.

I have tried many solution but same thing is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.